# Reading from JSON on Android

Tags: android, json

I have created an string in JSON format. It looks like:

```
private String jString = "{\"CategoryId\":1},{\"CategoryId\":2}";
```

and this is then initialized as an JSON object like this:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jString);
```

when reading I'm using:

```
j = jObject.getString("CategoryId");
```

I can read the first value but I can't read the second one. Any ideas on how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid JSON format. [Look here](http://www.json.org/) to see the format of a JSON object / array.

If you want to be able to read both values, create an array:

```
String jString = "[{\"CategoryId\":1},{\"CategoryId\":2}]";
JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(jString);
for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); ++i) {
    int i = jArr.getJsonObject(i).getInt("CategoryId");
    // do something with i which is an int, not a String
}
```

Comment: perfect, thanks alot. That solved my problem.. Thanks.. It was actually written with the [] just didnt got with thanks..