# passing arraylist item of tabfragment recyclerview to other activity recyclerview

Tags: json, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have fetched JSonarray data as string and have added it to arraylist i.e
this is done on a tab fragment recycler view .

```
      JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(index);
//                        Log.d("TAG", jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        int id =jsonObject.getInt("id");
                        String title=jsonObject.getString("title");
//                        Log.d("TAG", jsonObject.getString("description"));
                        String shortDec=jsonObject.getString("description");
                        String longDec=jsonObject.getString("short_description");
                        String imguUrl=jsonObject.getString("image");
                        String createdAt=jsonObject.getString("created_at");

//                        Toast.makeText(NewsDetailsActivity.this, "\nTitle: "+title+"\n Description:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        NewsListGetter newsListGetter=new NewsListGetter(id, title, shortDec,longDec,imguUrl,createdAt);
                        arrayList.add(newsListGetter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I have another activity called NewsDetailsAcivity,in which I have implemented a recycler view. 
I want to pass only the data from recylerview of tab1fragment which is clicked,to the newsDetailActivity recylerview.

Comment: Please, post `JSON` example

Comment: @Ziat is there any object inside JSONArray ?

Comment: post your json here

Comment: http://ec2-54-147-238-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com/hmc/api/getnewsfeeds?order=asc

this is a link to the json.. kindly sir have a look @Alexey #Shivam #nihal

Comment: @ShivamOberoi 
ec2-54-147-238-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com/hmc/api/… this is a link to the json.. kindly sir have a look

Comment: @nihal_softy 
ec2-54-147-238-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com/hmc/api/… this is a link to the json.. kindly  have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is already in JSONArray no need to store in another JSON Array.

Look at the code below.

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

String url = "http://ec2-54-147-238-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com/hmc/api/getnewsfeeds?order=asc";
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        for (int index = 0; index < response.length(); index++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(index);
                Log.d("TAG", jsonObject.getString("title"));
                Log.d("TAG", jsonObject.getString("description"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
});
requestQueue.add(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take Your Response.Listener in String first like

```
new Response.Listener<String>
```

Then Store your response in JSONObject, and then get JSONArray from stored JSONObject. Like this:

```
  JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response);
  JSONArray responseArray = data.getJSONArray("data"); // here data is Key of your JsonArray.
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: have you gone through the json data on the give url..there is no name of jsonArray

Comment: Then just Do like this:  JSONArray responseArray=new JSONArray(response);

Comment: then how i can get data using key and store them in respective string variable?
like if i want to fetch data in that array of "title" and "description" and store them in respective string vars @BhoomikaPatel

Comment: @xamMTS You can do something like this.

for(int index= 0;index < responseArray.length() ; index++{         Log.d(TAG,responseArray.getJSONObject(index).getString('title');
}
Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662657/reading-from-json-on-android) for more info

Comment: getting same error!! @BhoomikaPatel 
i did this following the link you provided 

                JSONArray jArr = null;
                try {
                    jArr = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); ++i) {
                        String des=jArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
                        Log.i("RESponse",des);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

Answer (score 0):

As per your JSON Response You can paste this code. I tasted this on my machine and working, Let me know if any issue is there

```
String json_url = "http://ec2-54-147-238-136.compute-.amazonaws.com/hmc/api/getnewsfeeds?order=asc";

JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject jObj = response.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.d("TAG", jObj.getString("title"));
            Log.d("TAG", jObj.getString("description"));
        } catch (JSONException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**How to save data in ArrayList**

*Create SampleModelClass*

```
public class SampleModelClass {

private String id;
private String description;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

*Now in your activity Where you are parsing JSON, Do the Same*

```
 JSONArray root_array = root_obj.getJSONArray("YOUR_ARRAY_NODE_NAME");
        for (int i = 0; i < root_array.length(); i++) {

            SampleModelClass commonModels = new SampleModelClass();
            JSONObject array_object = root_array.getJSONObject(i);
            commonModels.setId(array_object.optString("id"));
            commonModels.setDescription("description");
            common_stop_list.add(commonModels);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: what if I want to put the fetched data to an arrayList instead of respective strings..

Comment: @ZiafatRaheemKhokhar Create a  model class.  and Use this Model Class to store. Like 

ArrayList<Model_Class> list = new ArrayList<>();
ModelClass model = new ModelClass();
model.setId(jObj.optString("id"));
----------------------------
----------------------------
list.add(model);

Comment: @ZiafatRaheemKhokhar Model Class means Setter and Getter Class.

Comment: I am doing the same as you mentioned above but it is not working for me.. @nihal_softl

Comment: @ZiafatRaheemKhokhar  wait I am updating my answer

Comment: @ZiafatRaheemKhokhar so any  crash or issue ?

Comment: sir you there??

Comment: @ZiafatRaheemKhokhar I think you are still in problem.. Okay clear let me know your requirement. I will code for you and will send you entire project.. :-)

Comment: @ZiafatRaheemKhokhar What is your requirement ? I got your JSON URL.. Now Let me know your need on write2nihal@gmail.com